# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "505c621128f97f31c5870f2a9e2d274fa432bd0

Tags: scala, sbt

Running the sbt test, I've got the following error message:

```
error] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "505c621128f97f31c5870f2a9e2d274fa432bd0e"
[error]         at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
[error]         at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
[error]         at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong(StringLike.scala:305)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong$(StringLike.scala:305)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:29)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatus$.$anonfun$read$1(TestStatusReporter.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatus$.$anonfun$read$1$adapted(TestStatusReporter.scala:42)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatus$.read(TestStatusReporter.scala:42)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatusReporter.succeeded$lzycompute(TestStatusReporter.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatusReporter.succeeded(TestStatusReporter.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.TestStatusReporter.doComplete(TestStatusReporter.scala:31)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.$anonfun$createTestTasks$7(TestFramework.scala:240)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.$anonfun$createTestTasks$7$adapted(TestFramework.scala:240)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.$anonfun$safeForeach$1(TestFramework.scala:150)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.$anonfun$safeForeach$1$adapted(TestFramework.scala:149)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.safeForeach(TestFramework.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.TestFramework$.$anonfun$createTestTasks$1(TestFramework.scala:226)
[error]         at sbt.Tests$.$anonfun$testTask$1(Tests.scala:231)
[error]         at sbt.Tests$.$anonfun$testTask$1$adapted(Tests.scala:231)
[error]         at sbt.std.TaskExtra$$anon$1.$anonfun$fork$2(TaskExtra.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3.$anonfun$apply$2(System.scala:46)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "505c621128f97f31c5870f2a9e2d274fa432bd0e"
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 522 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 3
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 3, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Passed: Total 3, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 3
```

As you can see, all test passed. What is wrong? Hint, I am using Intellij.

**Update**

Here is the code:

```
import atto._
import Atto._
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

sealed trait PcpPair

case class PcpHead(key: String, value: String) extends PcpPair

case class PcpFieldValue(field: String, value: String) extends PcpPair

case class Pcp(head: List[PcpHead], fv: List[PcpFieldValue], body: String)


object PcpProtocol {

  implicit val pcpProtocol: Protocol[Pcp] = new Protocol[Pcp] {
    override def encode(text: String): ProtocolResult[Pcp] =
      doc
        .parseOnly(text)
        .either
        .flatMap { t =>
          isValidPcp(t._1) match {
            case true => Right(t)
            case false => Left("It is not a valid PCP protocol.")
          }
        }
        .map(t => Pcp(filterPcpHead(t._1), filterFieldValue(t._1), t._2))

    override def decode(msg: Pcp): String = ???
  }

  private val PcpValidity = "pcp-"

  private val key = stringOf(letter | char('-'))
  private val value = stringOf(notChar('\n'))
  private val kv = (key <~ char(':')) ~ value
  private val kvs = sepBy(kv, char('\n'))
  private val doc = (kvs <~ string("\n\n")) ~ takeText


  private val isValidPcp: List[(String, String)] => Boolean = textList =>
    textList
      .map(kv => kv._1.startsWith(PcpValidity))
      .foldLeft(true)(_ || _)

  private val filterPcpHead: List[(String, String)] => List[PcpHead] = textList =>
    textList
      .filter(text => text._1.contains(PcpValidity))
      .map(text => PcpHead(text._1, text._2))

  private val filterFieldValue: List[(String, String)] => List[PcpFieldValue] = textList =>
    textList
      .filter(text => !text._1.contains(PcpValidity))
      .map(text => PcpFieldValue(text._1, text._2))

  private val decodeHead: List[PcpHead] => String = heads =>
    heads.foldLeft("") { (acc, value) =>
      acc |+| value.key |+| ":" |+| value.value |+| "\n"
    }

  private val decodePair: List[PcpPair] => ((String, PcpPair) => String) => String = pcpList => fnPcp =>
    pcpList.foldLeft("")(fnPcp)

}
```

and here is the test:

```
class PcpParserSpec extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  val valid =
    """pcp-action:MESSAGE
      |pcp-channel:apc\:///
      |pcp-body-type:text
      |PUBLICKEY:THISPK
      |TOPIC:SEND
      |
      |Hello Foo""".stripMargin

  describe("Receive message from SAP server") {


    it("should contains pcp-channel:apc") {
      Protocol.encode(valid) should be('right)
    }

    it("should be separated by head and body") {
      Protocol.encode(valid) match {
        case Right(value) => assert(value.head.length > 0)
        case Left(text) => assert(text.length > 0)
      }
    }

    describe("The body of the message") {

      it("should contains Hello Foo") {

        Protocol.encode(valid) match {
          case Right(value) => assert(value.body == "Hello Foo")
          case Left(text) => assert(text.length > 0)
        }
      }
    }

  }

  describe("Send message to SAP") {

    it("should encode appropriate PCP protocol") {

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Just because something prints exception to stdout doesn't cause the test to fail. 
It would only fail if an exception is thrown on the test's thread, _and_ is not caught.

Comment: What had happen?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: I have just encountered this - new computer, setting up. I isolated it to `class Test extends FunSpec` :(.  I have a NumberFormatException for "" ... and I'm on openjdk 11.0.1 Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll probably find is that `target/streams/test/test/\$global/streams/succeeded_tests` (in your project directory) is getting garbled. (Mine was an encoded mess).

You should be getting something like

```
#Successful Tests
#Thu Apr 04 07:54:33 NZDT 2019
MyTest=1554317673393
```

The number it's trying to read is after the `=`.

The confusing bit (to me) is that it's outputting the summary - mine didn't when it failed parsing.

**Before you run the following**, could you share (some of) the contents of `succeeded_tests` (above) in a comment here (I'm curious to see these failures).

`sbt clean test` should fix you up...